# Remove ~ in buffer at vim startup

Tags: vimrc, gvim

When open vim or kill buffers to empty I encounter with `~` and I'd like to disable/remove it.

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### In Vim 8

```
:highlight EndOfBuffer ctermfg=bg guifg=bg
```

### In earlier versions

```
:highlight NonText ctermfg=bg guifg=bg
```

(But this will also hide other things. See `:help hl-NonText` and `:help 'listchars'`)