# Don't show grey boundaries between windows

Tags: vim-windows

I am using vim as a book reader.
For this purpose I have three windows open as shown

```
  ________________________________________ 
 |~           ||The book I'm||~           |  
 |~           ||reading here||~           |  
 |~           ||It's a braw ||~           |  
 |~           ||licht moon  ||~           |  
 |~           ||licht nicht ||~           |  
 |~           ||the nicht in||~           |  
 |~           ||Echt        ||~           |  
  ________________________________________
```

I am reading in the middle window only.
This way I get a page about the same width as a book, and it makes for comfortable reading.

Can I turn the visible vertical borders between windows off so I don't see them?

Answer (score 4):

To get rid of the `|` character between vertical windows you can set `'fillchars'`'s `vert` option to space. See `:h 'fillchars'` for more infomation

```
set fillchars+=vert:\
```

NOTE: there is a space being escaped at the end of the line

Comment: thanks. With the escaped space at the end of the line included it places the backslash vertically in the middle of the grey vertical bar, on each row. The grey vertical bar does not dissapear.

Answer (score 3):

You can set foreground and background of the `VertSplit` highlighting group to the background color of your Vim instance:

```
:hi VertSplit ctermfg=bg ctermbg=bg guifg=bg guibg=bg
```

Comment: thanks. I tried that and get the `E420: BG colour unknown` error. I tried `:set bg=dark` before hand but this made little difference

Comment: @Kes I think this happens, because Vim does not know the default background color. Try to also explicitly set the Normal highlighting group using `:hi Normal ctermfg=white ctermbg=black` (or similar)

Comment: @Christian-Brabandt that worked, thanks. Do you know how I can turn off the one character width column of full screen height `~`s shown on the left hand side of both the left hand and right hand windows? I have updated the diagram above to show the two columns of `~`s

Comment: @Kes see this question for removing the end of buffer marker: https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/14225/remove-in-buffer-at-vim-startup

Comment: @andrew-ho-lee, thanks. That worked. I was also trying to find what the default `bg` and `fg` colors were with attempts like `hi Normal ctermfg?` but that returned an error. Any idea how I get these?

Comment: @Kes `:hi Normal` will tell you what that highlight group is defined as. More generally, `:h :highlight` is a useful read for how colours are set.

Comment: It this the same effect as setting them `NONE`?

Comment: @job_start No, not completely. For the background colors it would not make a difference, but for the foreground color Vim would then use the Normal foreground color instead of the background color as with `ctermfg=bg` and `guifg=bg`. This two `...bg` values were chosen to make the actual glyph "invisible".

Answer (score 3):

You might want to check out the [Goyo](https://github.com/junegunn/goyo.vim) plug-in, which uses Vim windows to create a focus area at the center of the screen, free of distractions.

See an example screenshot below:

[image: Screenshot of Goyo]

Comment: thanks @Filbranden, I will check it out. Currently I am using Vim Mutton plug-in https://github.com/gabenespoli/vim-mutton.git. Seems Goyo may be a better choice.

Comment: hi @Filbranden, i've tested Goyo. That's a very nice plugin. I've already started using it! :)